# Discrete Event Simulation Time Unit in Java

Tags: java, clock, seed

I am working on a discrete event simulation in Java, the code related the time is below;

```
class Event implements Runnable, Comparable {
    double time;
    Runnable runnable;

    Event(double time, Runnable aRunnable) {
        this.time = time;
        runnable = aRunnable;
    }

    public boolean lessThan(Comparable y) {
        Event e = (Event) y; // Will throw an exception if y is not an Event
        return this.time <= e.time;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        runnable.run();

    }
}

class Simulator extends AbstractSimulator {

    static Random rnd;
    static double time;
    double endTime;


    static double now() {
        return time;
    }

    Simulator(long seed, double simDuration) {
        time = 0.0;
        events = new ListQueue();
        rnd = new Random(seed);
        endTime = simDuration;
    }

    void doAllEvents() {
        Event e;
        while ((e = (Event) events.removeFirst()) != null && time < endTime) {
            if(time > e.time)
                System.out.printf("Something is worng! time=%f eventtime=%f",time,e.time);
            time = e.time;
            e.run();
            System.out.printf("\n Time = %f", time);

        }
    }
```

I consider results based on an event failing time, but I need to use a unit for the time when I plot it.

Which unit Java uses for the simulation time? Or can I just consider them as second ? Or is there any calculations to convert it real world time?

Thanks in advance,

Best Regards,

UPDATE:

Thanks for the answers, I tried to measure the exact time but I have a problem here. The existing virtual simulation time is measuring a network lifetime. And it is not working same as exact time for an example; When I run the simulation for 75 devices the netorklifetime is shorter lets say 70.0 but the real time is more than 35 devices with 1500.0 lifetime. That happens because the events are repeating for each device.

What I need here finding the unit for the virtual simulation time.

Thanks again...

Comment: Note: implement `Comparable<Event>`, not raw `Comparable`.

Comment: For time I would use System.nanoTime() (long )and TimeUnit class to present them. nanoTime() is there just to measure time elapsed

Answer (score 1):

You may use `ScheduledExecutorService` to simulate discrete events, like

```
List<Event> events = new ArrayList<Event>();
ScheduledExecutorService executor =  Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(4);
for (Event event : events) {
    executor.schedule(event, (long) event.time, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
try {
    executor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Several points, which may be helpful:

1. I don't think it is worth to set the size of the pool more than number of cores you have (4 in example above)
2. There is no need for `Event` to implement `Comparable` for the snippet above
3. I would use `long` type for time field rather than `double`

**UPDATE** In case you don't want to use executors or threads, you may sort events by time and wait until event should be triggered using `while` loop as below:

```
List<Event> events = new ArrayList<Event>();
events.add(new Event(1000d, () -> System.out.println("event1")));
events.add(new Event(2000d, () -> System.out.println("event2")));
//adding more events ...
Collections.sort(events);

//Fix start time
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
for (Event event : events) {

    //Wait until event time is <= than current - start time
    while (event.time > System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
    event.run();
}
```